# Audio Context not loading on time

Tags: audio, audiocontext, soundfont

I have a component which uses Soundfont to play a note which loads by useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => { // fix loading 
        const ac = new AudioContext();
        soundfontInstrument(ac, 'acoustic_grand_piano', { soundfont: 'MusyngKite' })
          .then((acoustic_grand_piano) => {
            somePiano = acoustic_grand_piano;
            setPiano(acoustic_grand_piano);
            console.log("piano is ready");
            setIsPianoReady(true);
          });
    
        return () => {
          ac.close();
        };
      }, []);
```

When I load the page the first time, setPiano and setIsPianoReady is called as expected but the button doesnt play any sound. It is until I refresh the page or reload the component that it only plays sound. The useEffect is a child component.

I have tried using async and await functions for my playNote function but it doesnt work either. I was expecting the Soundfont to actually play sound

```
async function handlePlayNote() {
        if (piano) {
            try { 
                if (Array.isArray(tone)) {
                    if (questionType === 'scales'){
                    // Play notes sequentially with a delay
                        for (const note of tone) { 
                            await piano.play(note);
                            // Introduce a delay between notes
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                        }
                        console.log("Played notes: " + tone.join(', '));
                    } else {
                        await Promise.all(tone.map(note => piano.play(note)));
                        console.log("Played notes: " + tone.join(', '));
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Invalid tone format:", tone);
                }
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error playing notes:", error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Piano not ready");
        }
    }
```